# attach string variable to ranked column values

Tags: java, sql

i had help here to update a table column with values from a computed ranked column.how can i attach string variables to them such that instead of values like 1,2,3,4...they will be 1st,2nd, 3rd,4th..
i wrote this code :

```
//code create computed ranked column
    String sql1 = SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT s2.Total) AS Rank from class1 s1 
    JOIN class1 s2 on (s1.Total<=s2.Total)
    GROUP BY s1.ID order by s1.Name ASC;
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql1);
    rs = pst.executeQuery();

    // attaching a string variable to the resultset
        String type = rs.getString(2);
            typ=Integer.parseInt(type);
            String type1 = "";
            if(typ==1){
            type1="st";
          }else if(typ==2){
            type1="nd";
            }else if(typ==3){
            type1="rd";
            }else if(typ>3){
            type1="th";
            }

//updating table column with the resultset
            String sql = "";
            while (rs.next()) { 
            sql = "update class1 set Position='"+rs.getString(2)+type1+"'"+" WHERE ID="+rs.getString(1); 
           pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
           pst.execute();
```

but what this does is to repeat the result of the first row to all the rows..

| NAME  | SCORE 1 | SCORE 2 | TOTAL | POSITION | 
------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
| james  |      10.0      |      24.0    |   34.0    |       1st       | 
| jimmy  |      10.0      |      20.0    |   30.0    |       2st       | 
| josh     |      10.0      |      19.0    |   29.0    |       3st       |

how do i get it to work like

| NAME  | SCORE 1 | SCORE 2 | TOTAL | POSITION | 
------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
| james  |      10.0      |      24.0    |   34.0    |       1st       | 
| jimmy  |      10.0      |      20.0    |   30.0    |       2nd      | 
| josh     |      10.0      |      19.0    |   29.0    |       3rd       |

thank you.

Comment: What data type is position in the database  appers to be int...?  If so, you may not be able to append st, nd, rd if it's an int data type... and @OHGODSPIDERS  notice position says `st` on all record in first table and `st`, `nd`, `rd` in 2nd table.

Comment: in the column named position, for the first table, the values are 1st,2st,3st.. but i want the values there to be 1st,2nd, 3rd like that of the second table... so xQbert,  i should change the data type to TEXT or VARCHAR

Comment: IMO you could just have a function that adds the st, nd and rd as needed or a case statement which adds it for display.   Why store it?  you run into problems sorting later if it gets to be 10th 100th 1000th... as the string data will not sort the same as the numeric data.  Why does this value need to be stored I guess is my question.  I'd rater keep the value numeric in the database and alter it on display as needed.

Comment: @xQbert You're right, i didn't spot that. I would guess that is because RodneyNart only generates your String type1 before he iterates the results in the while loop. Try to move that calculation into your while loop so you calculate what String type1 is before every update statement.

Comment: and I missed the setting of the value once instead of in the iterative.  But I still don't see why storing the st, nd etc is needed.  I'd rater use a function and change it on the display storing the numeric.

Comment: i store it because i want to create a report from it with jasper report, which can later be printed out.. if its for only display, can i get jasper to display the case statements by the side of the values?

Comment: I'd assume so; your column value for that would  look like this in the select  `Case colName when 1 then '1st' when 2 then '2nd' when 3 then 3rd' end as Position`  assuming you only have 3 positions.  Alternatively you could create a lookup table which you join to.  This allows you to transate 1 to 1st and 2 to 2nd etc...  but that seems like overkill.  Or instead of a case use a SQL function passing in colName and return the desired value.  If you change it, how will people maintain it.. Will it still be a numeric, will you need new validation rules ?  Keeping it numeric seems wiser to me.

Comment: Changing data in a database to improve the display seems like a bad idea to me.  Writing a function that consumes the data and outputs it in the desired format seems wiser as it doesn't change how the data is maintained.  Either a lookup table to translate the values or a function that can be called in the database to translate the values both seem viable options to me.

Comment: ok will try that

Comment: @OH GOD SPIDERS, your suggestion also worked.. moving the case statements into the while loop solved it. though the column is an int data type, i had no exceptions or errors and the results were as i expected..ranked as, 1st,2nd,3rd,4th,5th,6th....10th,11th etc..@Qbert. but will take your advice too and get another function to read the values in the column and append the necessary case statment to it since thats the right way to code.. thank you all. stay blessed.